# Cannot figure out how to memoize subset function

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, recursion, tuples

My function is supposed to find whether or not the values of a number list add up to my target in any way shape or form.  My code is:

```
def memoizedSubset(target, numberList, memo):
    ''' Returns True if there exists a subset of numberList that adds
        up to target and returns False otherwise.'''
    if target == 0:
        return True;
    elif numberList == ():
        return False;
    elif (target, numberList) in memo:
        return memo[(target, numberList)];
    elif numberList[0] > target:
        solution = memoizedSubset(target, numberList[1:], memo);
        memo[(target, numberList)] = solution;
        return solution;
    else:
        useIt = memoizedSubset(target - numberList[0], numberList, memo);
        loseIt = memoizedSubset(target, numberList[1:], memo);
        solution = useIt or loseIt;
        memo[(target, numberList)] = solution;
        return solution;

numberTuple = tuple(range(2, 100, 2));
print(memoizedSubset(1234567, numberTuple, {}));
```

The logic seems flawless but when I try to run the function I get the maximum recursion depth reached error.  I used a dictionary to speed up the process because with the given values it would take a while to complete it without a dictionary.  I cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is.

UPDATE: The code works for smaller values but not for a larger value like 1234567 above.  Isn't memoization supposed to get over the recursion limit hump?

Comment: You're trying to use really, really deep recursion. You're hitting the recursion depth limit. Pick an algorithm that doesn't recurse so deep.

Comment: It's not a problem with the memoization. Your memoization logic is fine.

Comment: The first `if` statement should be: `if target == 0: return True`. Otherwise there's no `True` returned. (0 == False). Isn't it?

Comment: @falsetru yea i just fixed that actually in my code il edit it here quick

Comment: It should be `True`, not `true`.

Comment: @user2357112 is there anyway i can get rid of the console recursion limit?

Comment: Are you supposed to be able to use input numbers repeatedly? Your algorithm currently tries to use multiple copies of input numbers.

Comment: @user2357112 yes I am making it so any number can be used an indefinite amount of times. However many needed to find a subset

Comment: "Subset" is pretty misleading, then. You're not finding subsets.

Comment: "Isn't memoization supposed to get over the recursion limit hump?" - no. Memoization is not intended to solve recursion limit issues. It decreases the number of redundant recursive calls a recursive function makes, but it is not guaranteed to make the call stack shallower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the memoization logic and adding `print(target, numberList[:5])` to the top of the function gives:

```
(1234567, (2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
(1234565, (2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
(1234563, (2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
(1234561, (2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
(1234559, (2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
(1234557, (2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
(1234555, (2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
(1234553, (2, 4, 6, 8, 10))
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raymond/Documents/tmp3.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(memoizedSubset(1234, numberTuple, {}));
  File "/Users/raymond/Documents/tmp3.py", line 16, in memoizedSubset
    useIt = memoizedSubset(target - numberList[0], numberList, memo);
```

This shows that the recursion is proceeding much too slowly for this to ever work.

Even adding [`sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) does not alleviate the problem.

Debugging code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

def memoizedSubset(target, numberList, memo):
    ''' Returns True if there exists a subset of numberList that adds
        up to target and returns False otherwise.'''
    print(target, numberList[:5])
    if target == 0:
        return 0;
    elif numberList == ():
        return False;
    elif numberList[0] > target:
        solution = memoizedSubset(target, numberList[1:], memo);
        return solution;
    else:
        useIt = memoizedSubset(target - numberList[0], numberList, memo);
        loseIt = memoizedSubset(target, numberList[1:], memo);
        solution = useIt or loseIt;
        return solution;

numberTuple = tuple(range(2, 100, 2));
print(memoizedSubset(1234567, numberTuple, {}));
```

Comment: yes but the elif should only get triggered if the first element in the tuple array is greater than the target. if it's not, it should use the value hence the target-numberList[0]

Comment: That looks fine to me. I'm pretty sleepy, so I might be thinking about it wrong, but the `elif` will get hit when the new target is small enough, right?

Comment: @user2357112 yes and when it does it will simply not use that element and skip over it.

Comment: "But adding sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) did not alleviate the problem" - it looks to me like the algorithm is simply trying to use a finite amount of recursion more than 10000 calls deep, but not infinite.

Comment: You can see that it [doesn't hit the recursion limit](http://ideone.com/RUARND) for smaller inputs.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, you're right.  So in fact the issue is that for larger inputs the recursion levels get far too deep and proceed too slowly towards termination.    The debugging prints show the none of the calls is duplicated before erroring-out, so memoization doesn't help at all.

Comment: You guys are right.  I appreciate the help.  Far too much computing power is needed for this to work at such high numbers that I do not have haha. @RaymondHettinger

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem in memoization itself. But you could use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) instead if you are using Python 3.4+ (no need to pass memo yourself).

- `if target == 0: return 0` should be `if target == 0: return True`. Otherwise the function always return False (0 == False); edited in the question after I commented.
- `useIt = memoizedSubset(target - numberList[0], numberList, memo)` should be `useIt = memoizedSubset(target - numberList[0], numberList[1:], memo)`

  - numberList is never reduced.
- Assuming `numberList` is sorted, you can return `False` immediately in case of `numberList[0] > target`.
- You can combine following lines into one to take a benefit of short-circuit (even though `useIt` is True, `loseIt` part would be executed otherwise)

  ```
  useIt = memoizedSubset(target - numberList[0], numberList, memo);
  loseIt = memoizedSubset(target, numberList[1:], memo);
  solution = useIt or loseIt;
  ```

---

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def solve(target, numbers):
    # assuming numbers is a sorted tuple of `int`s.
    if target == 0:
        return True
    elif (not numbers) or numbers[0] > target:
        return False
    else:
        return solve(target - numbers[0], numbers[1:]) or \
               solve(target, numbers[1:])
```